# Compact LINQ syntax for float ranges?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a **compact, built-in** way to generate a range of floats from `min` to `max` with a given `step`?

E.g.: range(10, 20, 0.1)   [but built-in].

Comment: How do you envision this working with, or how does this relate to, LINQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100).Select(i => i / 10F)
```

But it isn't very descriptive.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's nothing built in. It would be really easy to write your static method though. Something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> FloatRange(float min, float max, float step)
{
    for (float value = min; value <= max; value += step)
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

EDIT: An alternative using multiplication, as suggested in comments:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> FloatRange(float min, float max, float step)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        float value = min + step * i;
        if (value > max)
        {
            break;
        }
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

In [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) I have some range code which does funky stuff thanks to Marc Gravell's generic operator stuff, allowing you:

```
foreach (float x in 10f.To(20f).Step(0.1f))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Just curious about a built-in version. :-)

Comment: Don't use addition, use multiplication for better precision.

Comment: If you want to ensure that you'll hit `max` in the range you'll need an approximate comparison to `max` in the for loop instead of just `<=`. Repeated additions could have you end up slightly higher than the given `max` value. Alternatively you could increment until you're one step less than max and `yield return max;` at the end.

Comment: i think comment should be like this "Very very thanks ! Dear jon "

Comment: @Ron: Yes, you could end up being slightly higher than the given max value - in which case `max` wouldn't be returned, but you'll still terminate. If you want to absolutely guarantee that `max` is returned, you would need to change it, I agree.